# freeglut's glutStrokeString giving a "stroke font not found error"

Tags: opengl, fonts, freeglut

I am trying to use `glutStrokeString` using freeglut.
The program runs fine up to the point it has to call `glutStrokeString`, then it outputs the console `freeglut stroke font not found`.

Any idea why?

Comment: Where do you get the font you pass to `glutStrokeString`?

Comment: @Nicol - I just use a glut constant, e.g `glutStrokeString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, "text to render");` - Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18`, as the name suggests, is a *bitmap* font. You can't use them with the `Stroke` rendering commands. So if you want to use that font, you have to use `glutBitmapString`.

FreeGLUT comes with two stroke fonts: `GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN` and `GLUT_STROKE_MONO_ROMAN`. So if you want to use the stroke commands to render the fonts, you have to use one of those kinds of fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Just check out the file, gluit/freeglut_font.c, in your glut source code, contains everything you need to know, Also check `fghFontByID() and fghStrokeByID()` which are actually used to computed the font id for both the functions that is `glutBitmapString()` & `glutStrokeString()`
or check out [this](http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/proj/trimesh2/src/trimesh2-2.11/gluit/freeglut_font.c)